# Monitor configured outside of supported operating frequencies

Tags: 12.04, drivers, screen

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I have a LG CRT FLATRON E700SH model monitor, and whenever I log into Ubuntu I get a message saying:

```
OUT OF FREQUENCY
HF:92.7kHz
VF:58.0 Hz

OPERATING FREQUENCY
HF:30-70KHz
VF:50-160 Hz
```

Please help me solve this problem if anyone knows it because I tried many of solutions.  I have also tried switching to tty1  through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> without success.

Comment: when did you get this message? you said login. did you see the purple screen and login screen? or just after reboot you saw this error. Are you trying it in live mode?

Comment: More interesting would details of the video card / chip.  VGA cable?  etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe in your question at first seemed similliar to the problem in the question linked below.
[Error message "Signal out of range 92KHz - 58Hz " when starting Ubuntu. What is wrong and how can I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/132885/52923)

The main difference seems to be in the situation described in that question Ubuntu would successfully start, but apparently this does not happen for you?

Have you installed Ubuntu? If so, how did you do the install? (I am wondering why you did not also have this problem when you booted a Live CD or USB)