# Blank screen after logging in

Tags: installation

I just installed the 64 bit version onto my laptop. It is the only operating system on the computer. After the initial setup and restart, I tried to log in, but after I typed my password and hit enter, the screen just went black. Tried to restart several times and had the same problem. Not sure what to do. I tried to use the 32 bit version instead but it doesn't even install. My computer is 64 bit, 200 g hard drive, 2 ghz processor, 4 g ram

Comment: see if this helps
[error-message-signal-out-of-range-92khz-58hz-when-starting-ubuntu-what-is][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132885/error-message-signal-out-of-range-92khz-58hz-when-starting-ubuntu-what-is/

Answer (score 0):

go in to your bios and change your SATA configuration to AHCI Mode also you may have to run install with --nomodeset

try just changing your config first. if that still dosent work then add --nomodeset
or --fb=false
or --vga=788